# Error: spawn chromedriver when ng e2e -- --protractor-config=./e2e/protractor-ci.conf.js on config.yml file

Tags: protractor, continuous-integration

I am trying to integrate protractor e2e tests on my circleCi with the following setup:

**config.yml**

```
- run:
          name: NPM test
          command: |
            cd frontend
            npm install
            apk update
            apk add chromium
            export CHROME_BIN=$(which chromium-browser)
            npm run test -- --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI --code-coverage || exit 0
      - run:
          name: Protractor e2e tests
          command: |
            cd frontend
            npm run e2e -- --protractor-config=./e2e/protractor-ci.conf.js
```

**protractor config:**

```
const config = require('./protractor.conf').config;

config.capabilities = {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox']
    }
};
```

exports.config = config;
Unit test run with success, although e2e tests are not running:

```
[10:12:58] I/file_manager - creating folder /root/project/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[10:12:58] I/config_source - curl -o/root/project/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[10:12:58] I/downloader - curl -o/root/project/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_81.0.4044.69.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/81.0.4044.69/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[10:12:59] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_81.0.4044.69.zip
[10:12:59] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /root/project/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_81.0.4044.69
[10:12:59] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:12:59] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[10:12:59] E/launcher - spawn /root/project/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_81.0.4044.69 ENOENT
[10:12:59] E/launcher - Error: spawn /root/project/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_81.0.4044.69 ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
[10:12:59] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

**Setup:**

- Angular CLI: 7.3.9
- Node: 10.19.0
- Protractor: 5.4.3

Already tried:
- Update webdriver before the tests started.
- Already check thatc hromedriver_81.0.4044.69 file is on the folder of the error

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I experience the exact same error.